# Как kaspi использует c# интегрированные платежи

Tags: c#

у кого-нибудь есть интегрированный партнер, которому платит каспий?

Моя система хочет использовать kaspi для оплаты, язык программирования IOS и андроид на передней стороне, язык программирования на задней стороне — C#, но я не могу найти официальный платежный документ кассапи и соответствующую статью технической поддержки,

Могу я узнать адрес официального платежного документа кассапи? Могу я спросить, есть ли у кассапи официальные примеры кода на GitHub? Пожалуйста, помогите мне с подсказкой

Я пыталась найти официальные документы для разработки и технические статьи форума, но ничего не нашла, и я хочу, чтобы вы все мне сказали, где находится официальный адрес платежной документации для kaspi pay? На гитубе есть код для примера? Или расскажите мне, что вам известно, и, пожалуйста, дайте мне подсказку

Comment: Что за языки программирования такие: IOS и андроид?

Comment: Здравствуйте, я хочу использовать Kaspi Pay для оплаты в моем собственном разработанном приложении, а серверная часть написана на C#. Вы знаете, где я могу найти техническую документацию на API веб-сервисов Kaspi Pay? Спасибо.